# Repeated application of interesting function on tuples

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This question was inspired by Thursday's CIMC.

Suppose you have a function $$f_n: (\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z})^n\to(\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z})^n; (a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n)\mapsto (b_1,b_2,b_3,\dots,b_n)$$ defined as follows:

Each $b_i$ is the number of occurrences of the integer $i-1$ in the tuple $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n)$

For example, with the function $f_4$:
$$(2,3,0,3)\mapsto(1,0,1,2)$$
$$(1,0,1,2)\mapsto(1,2,1,0)$$
$$(3,3,3,1)\mapsto(0,1,0,3)$$
$$\dots$$
I found that the general function $f_n$ exhibited some rather interesting properties. For example, the fixed points (where $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\mapsto (a_1,\dots,a_n)$) must be of a specific form (left to the reader), and the components of the image must always sum to $n$.

Ok, question time: if given such a function and a specific tuple, is there any way to find out right from the start how many repeated applications of the function it takes until the tuples start repeating? For example, the first two maps above show the function $f_4$ repeated on generations of the tuple $(2,3,0,3)$. As is obvious, it takes only $2$ applications of the function before the tuples start repeating, since $(1,2,1,0)\mapsto(1,2,1,0)$.

So is there a general rule for $f_n$ on any tuple $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$?

Comment: What is CIMC???

Comment: @bof That's not the point here. If you must know, it's the Canadian Intermediate Mathematics Competition, a popular contest held by the University of Waterloo.

Comment: EDIT Sorry, ignore this comment.  What do you do with the n-tuple $ ( 1, 1, \ldots , 1) \mapsto (0, n, 0, \ldots , 0) \mapsto $ ??? There is nowhere to record the $ n $ since the n-tuple only records numbers upto $ n-1 $.

Comment: The general rule is to iterate the function until the tuples start repeating. I doubt there is anything as general but simpler.

Comment: @Nick Let's just say it stops, for simplicity.